# aria-describedby - Same description for two fields?

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria, wcag2.0

Assuming the code below:

```
<label for="cars">Choose a car:</label>

<select name="carType" id="cars" aria-describedby="feedback">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

<label for="carPrice">Enter a purchase price:</label>

<input id="carPrice" type="number" aria-describedby="feedback"></input>

<div id="feedback">The {car} you are considering for {carPrice} is {good/bad} value.</div>
```

I have used the **aria-describedby** attribute relating to the **feedback** div twice.  Is this acceptable use?  I haven't found any documentation that says this isn't allowed, however it seems there might be another solution.

Kind regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with several elements pointing to the same `aria-describedby` element.  Both "carType/cars" and "carPrice" can point to "feedback".

Note that your first `<select>` will not have a label because the `<label for="carType">` is using the wrong ID in the `for` attribute.  Your `<select>` has a **name** attribute of "carType" but **name** is used for javascript access.  The `for` attribute should refer to the value of the `ID` attribute.  So you need to change your `<label>` to `<label for="cars">`

Comment: Succinct and to the point and a nice catch on the label! +1 from me bud!

Comment: Thanks for the catch! I should probably test my example code.  I'll update it for anyone that comes across this question.